# Was there an evolution of the Greek alphabet in the Middle East?

Tags: greek, writing-systems, evolution, alphabets

I recently visited Jordan and noticed that many mosaic are commented
with included text. The text seems mostly ancient Greek alphabet, but
it also contains non Greek characters such as **C**, obviously
standing for Σ, at least for some words. Given I forgot most I ever
knew of Greek, I mostly looked at city names.

For example yous have the cities [**NϵAΠOΛIC**](http://www.christusrex.org/www1/ofm/mad/sources/sources035.html) and [**ΔIOCΠωΛIC**](http://www.christusrex.org/www1/ofm/mad/sources/sources086.html) on two mosaics
from the 8th century in the Church of St. Stephen at Umm al
Rasas. Note also the different spellings for city (POLIS).

Similarly. on the 6th century mosaic map of the Holy Land in the
Church of St George at Madaba, there is the city [**NIKOΠOΛIC**](http://www.soniahalliday.com/category-view3.php?pri=madaba-mosaic-j18-7-21jt.jpg).
Look below Bethleem (number 2) on the large this map:[image: h century map of Holy Land]

This cannot be the cyrillic alphabet, which does not contain ω and was
created in the ninth century anyway, its authors (saint Cyril and
Methodius being born between 815 and 827).

This seems to indicate and evolution in the use of Greek characters in
that part of the world. Unless the use of **C** was justified because
the ending sigma **ς** is not easily rendered in mosaic. This does not
seem too likely as mosaics are pretty good at that level of details (look at the **λ** for Bethleem).

Can someone give some light on this. Was there an evolution in
writing. How much of it was already done when the two brothers created
the Cyrillic alphabet, and would it explain some of the new characters
in it?

Also worth noting on the [third mosaic](http://www.soniahalliday.com/category-view3.php?pri=madaba-mosaic-j18-7-21jt.jpg) (map of the Holy Land) is the Greek spelling of
Bethleem, with two different epsilons: **BHϑλϵEM**. And there is also the frequent mixing of lower and upper case (if  I may called them that way, given the time). Was that common?

Comment: The Cyrillic alphabet does contain ω, it is still used in Church Slavonic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are all normal Greek characters. **C** is a form of sigma: it's called lunate sigma, and is a variant that's sometimes used in printed texts these days too. Lunate sigma is a Hellenistic development which occurred in handwritten Greek (not specific to mosaics) for speed of writing. (It's also the origin of the Cyrillic **C** for [s].)

In ΔIOCΠωΛIC the omega must be a spelling mistake: at this period Greek no longer distinguished the sound of omega (originally [ɔː]) from that of omicron ([o]), and such confusions are common. The two epsilons in "Bethlehem" look almost the same to me; one's a bit more rounded, but that's well within the usual range of shape variation in pre-print era texts. The lowercase-uppercase distinction would not arise for another several centuries.

Comment: Thank you. I am a bit surprised by the answer as I never had any hint
in my ancient Greek textbooks. As I recall, event ancient texts were
written (in the books I had) following the modern use of uppercase and
lowercase. But then, when did the two character sets appear, and why?
How old are the most ancient original handwritten documents we have? Could the lunate sigma replace both sigmas or only the ending one **ς** ?

Comment: Lunate sigma is actually older than σ ς, which are derived from it by closing the loop and by adding a tail, respectively. Modern conventions of printing Greek are different from ancient ones in several ways: not just uppercase and lowercase but the use of spaces and punctuation, and of breathings and accents (another Hellenistic invention, which wasn't consistently used until Byzantine times). The lowercase/uppercase distinction basically arose with printing, which imported an existing manuscript convention of making some initial letters larger and fancier.

Comment: @babou No, neither Romans nor Greeks used upper/lower case the way it's used nowadays. Capital letters were used for inscriptions in monuments as well as books on stuff deemed of special importance (such as religious books or major works of poetry/history). Small letters were used always for mostly everything else when writing in papyrus, patch or the like. Have a look on photos of ancient hexagaplas to see how they're written in all minusculae, not capitals.

Comment: @babou If I recall it correctly, Lunate Sigma is simply a cursive form of capital sigma, so it can appear anywhere in the word.

Comment: @JoePineda Minuscule letters didn't exist in antiquity -- they're a Byzantine invention. The first known Greek minuscules are from the ninth century. Ancient papyri used basically the same letter forms as inscriptions, though with some adaptations for handwriting, like lunate sigma, lunate epsilon, a somewhat different alpha, and what is now the lowercase form of omega. (What are hexagaplas?)

Comment: @JoePineda If capitals were the rules for important document. Could it be the
case (no pun intended) that copyists actually switched to the faster
cursive/minuscule form for convenience, though retaining capitals for
important places in the text, so as to still mark its importance. And
this would have paved the way for printers practices, even before
printing was there? I realise for searching wikipedia, that all this
was a lot more complex and confused. After all, the first printers were only mimicking current writing practice.

Comment: @TKR Sorry, I meant "hexapla". You're right, looked for images of very old New Testament papyri and found they're just variations of capitals (mostly using lunate sigma and epsilon, as you said). Some images http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img705/331/mprsb.jpg http://goodgreeking.web04.yourhost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/MatthewEgyptEarly4thc.jpg etc. I guess we all get the wrong idea since modern teaching materials for Greek and Latin (and reprints of Bible and classical works) use modern spelling and punctuation conventions.